# JQuery Mobile How to use TouchPunch.js to move elements on page?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the touchPunch hack for a project I am working on so my dynamically created elements can move on the page. I am using web storm as my IDE and have gone through the step by step tutorial on how to properly use touchpunch. I have included the scripts needed:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"> 
    </script>

    <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

And then I create my div on the screen:

```
    <div id="square" style="width:25px; height:25px; background-color: blue"></div>
```

And then in my jquery I have this code:

```
    $("#square").draggable();
```

The problem is the draggable function is not being recognized and when i try to run the phonegap project on my phone through the apk, none of my elements move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is a few months old....but I stumbled across it and saw it was unanswered.

I updated the scripts in the head, and wrapped the jQuery in document ready and it now works.  I've used touchpunch along with jQuery ui / jQuery mobile in a couple Cordova apps and it works great.  Anyway, below works.  If you're still having issues open Safari or Chrome and inspect to see if there are any errors you're getting.  Good luck.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#square").draggable();
});
```

[Link to working codepen:](https://codepen.io/pschorey/pen/GzJErd)

Comment: When you say you used it with jquery mobile, what do you mean? I ask because JQM has touch events.